# Remove small-code style relocations from pre-built libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am experimenting with large binaries and found that even though binaries are built with `-mcmodel=large`, they can still contain small-code style PC32 relocation instructions which can throw errors at linking time. This happens because dynamically shared objects are already built with small-code model and `-mcmodel=large` does not remove the relocation instructions there.

One example. Consider this simple c++ code:

```
// too_large.cc

int main() {
  static int y = 0;
  asm volatile(".align 1073741824");
  y += 5;
  return 0;
}
```

Here the `.align` directive is used for artificially increasing the code size so that small-code model instructions, if present, throw error during linking. This gets compiled without any error (`g++ -mcmodel=large -c too_large.cc -o too_large.o`), but during linking (using `g++ too_large.o -o too_large`), this throws following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_GOTPCRELX against symbol `__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34' defined in .text section in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:(.eh_frame+0x20): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.text'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o: in function `_init':
(.init+0x7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX against undefined symbol `__gmon_start__'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o: in function `deregister_tm_clones':
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.tm_clone_table'
crtstuff.c:(.text+0xa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__TMC_END__' defined in .data section in too_large
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x16): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX against undefined symbol `_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o: in function `register_tm_clones':
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x33): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.tm_clone_table'
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x3a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__TMC_END__' defined in .data section in too_large
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x57): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX against undefined symbol `_ITM_registerTMCloneTable'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o: in function `__do_global_dtors_aux':
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x76): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
crtstuff.c:(.text+0x81): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
too_large: PC-relative offset overflow in GOT PLT entry for `__cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

The errors are coming from the object files of the compiler itself (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o). This happens as gcc is also built with small-code model.

Is there any way to force the compiler to emit only 64 bit offsets whenever large-code model is used?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the command you use to link your program.

Comment: @Bodo Sorry for missing that. Added now.

Comment: Just a guess: Does using the same `-mcmodel=large` in the linking step help?